# Bash: Extract multiple entries from each line

Tags: awk, gnu, unix-text-processing

I have a log file that looks somewhat like this after `grep my_function $LOG_FILE`:

```
[0] my_function took 96.78581194020808 ms
[1] my_function took 82.0779490750283 ms
[2] my_function took 187.79653799720109 ms
[1] my_function took 98.69955899193883 ms
[0] my_function took 10.296131949871778 ms[1] my_function took 2.5152561720460653 ms
[1] my_function took 2.210912061855197 ms
[2] my_function took 3.418975044041872 ms
```

From this file, I would like to only extract the numbers from each line. Normally, I would use `awk '{print $4}'` to do this, but this log contains a few lines with two entries. However, here, I sometimes need to select two separate entries from a single line. How can I appropriately select these with `bash`/GNU tools?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not ensure that your logs are denoted with a newline to solve the root issue?

Comment: That would be a possibility for the long term, but now, I've got this log file and if I re-run with proper logging, I wouldn't get another, properly formatted log file before next week.

Comment: You could use either `awk -F'[. ]' '/my_function/{print $4}' Input_file` OR `awk '/my_function/{print int($4)}' Input_file` for this one.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Those too select only the fourth column, but not the eighth column in the fifth line, that I'm actually after.

Comment: @Green绿色, sure, please do check my answer on same, cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` solutions. We need not to use `grep` to search string first and then print the required value(s), we could do both of these with `awk` itself.

Using GNU `awk` here.

```
awk '
{
  while(match($0,/my_function took (\S+)/,arr)){
     print arr[1]
     $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  }
}
' Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Setting `RS` as `my_function took (\\S+)` in GNU `awk` and dealing with `RT` and `split` functions later on to get required output as per shown samples.

```
awk -v RS='my_function took (\\S+)' 'RT && split(RT,arr,FS){print arr[3]}' Input_file
```

Comment: Nice, it works!

Answer (score 5):

You appear to sometimes have a second line after the first line with the same format, where the value of interest is in the 4th column.

If that is always the case, instead of printing the 4th column, you can print every column where `column_number % 4 == 0`

```
awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if (i%4 == 0) print $i }' file
```

Output

```
96.78581194020808
82.0779490750283
187.79653799720109
98.69955899193883
10.296131949871778
2.5152561720460653
2.210912061855197
3.418975044041872
```

Comment: Good use of modulo to solve this problem

Answer (score 4):

Using `gnu grep`:

```bash
grep -oP '\stook\s+\K\S+' file

96.78581194020808
82.0779490750283
187.79653799720109
98.69955899193883
10.296131949871778
2.5152561720460653
2.210912061855197
3.418975044041872
```

Where `\K` resets/discards previously matched text and `\S+` is 1+ of non-whitespace characters in next word after matching `took`.

Answer (score 4):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk '{for (i=4; i<NF; i+=4) print $i}' file
96.78581194020808
82.0779490750283
187.79653799720109
98.69955899193883
10.296131949871778
2.5152561720460653
2.210912061855197
3.418975044041872
```

or get rid of the initial `grep` you're doing and just run this one command:

```
$ awk '/my_function /{for (i=4; i<NF; i+=4) print $i}' "$LOG_FILE"
```

Alternatively, using GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT:

```
$ awk -v RS='my_function took [0-9.]+' 'RT{$0=RT; print $NF}' "$LOG_FILE"
96.78581194020808
82.0779490750283
187.79653799720109
98.69955899193883
10.296131949871778
2.5152561720460653
2.210912061855197
3.418975044041872
```

Answer (score 3):

Since all records in your input apparently end with `' ms'`, you can make it the record separator instead:

```
awk -vRS=' ms' '{print $4}'
```

Demo: https://awk.js.org/?snippet=zqn7kk

Comment: It needs to be `awk -vRS=' ms\n?' '{print $NF}'` or `awk -vRS=' ms' 'RT{print $4}'` or similar to avoid printing a blank line at the end of the output for `\n` after the final `ms`. You should also mention it requires GNU awk or some other awk that supports multi-char RS.

Answer (score 3):

I would exploit built-in GNU `AWK` variables for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
[0] my_function took 96.78581194020808 ms
[1] my_function took 82.0779490750283 ms
[2] my_function took 187.79653799720109 ms
[1] my_function took 98.69955899193883 ms
[0] my_function took 10.296131949871778 ms[1] my_function took 2.5152561720460653 ms
[1] my_function took 2.210912061855197 ms
[2] my_function took 3.418975044041872 ms
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="[0-9]+[.][0-9]+";OFS="\n"}NF{$1=$1;print}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
96.78581194020808
82.0779490750283
187.79653799720109
98.69955899193883
10.296131949871778
2.5152561720460653
2.210912061855197
3.418975044041872
```

Explanation: I instruct GNU `AWK` that field consist of one-or-more (`+`) digits followed by literal dot followed by one-or-more digits and that output field separator (`OFS`) should be newline. Then for line with at least one field found (`NF`) I do `$1=$1` to trigger rebuilt and `print` that. If you want to know more about `FPAT` or `OFS` or `NF` then read [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/).

**Disclaimer**: this solution assumes European fractions below 1 (like `0.5`) rather than U.S. fractions (like `.5`).

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*

Comment: I'm a European living in the US - I haven't noticed any difference in fraction terminology between the 2 and I couldn't find anything about that through google. Do you have a link or anything that talks about 0.5 being European vs .5 being US terminology? I'm just interested, that's all.

Comment: @EdMorton I do not have any standard at hand, but one example is [Year by Year Leaders for Batting Average](https://www.baseball-almanac.com/hitting/hibavg3.shtml)

Comment: thanks but that seems to be just some baseball batting averages. I do think they talk about `.whatever` for baseball averages but I don't think that's a difference between US and European formats, it's just what "they" decided to use for baseball. If you look at https://www.teamrankings.com/nfl/stat/interceptions-thrown-per-game it's showing American football interception stats using `0.whatever`.

Answer (score 1):

You could also pre-process the log file by sending the second record on the same line onto a line of its own and then do `awk { print $4 }`:

```bash
grep my_function $LOG_FILE | perl -pe 's| ms(?=\[\d+\])| ms\n|g' | awk { print $4 }
```

The `perl` one-liner replaces all  `ms` followed by `[<some-number>]` (and only those  `ms`) with an  `ms` and a new line. This will work even when there are more than two rows on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

A Ruby:

```
ruby -lne '$_.scan(/(\d+\.\d+) ms/).each{|m| puts m}' file
```

Or Perl:

```
perl -lnE 'say $1 while (/(\d+\.\d+) ms/g)' file
```